# "We shouldn't stand here" vs "We shouldn't be standing here"

Tags: difference

> We shouldn't stand here

and

> We shouldn't be standing here

What is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence sounds like there is **certainty**, that it is a command to not stand at a particular location

The second, **be standing here**, sounds more contemplative

If **we** is changed for **you**

> **You shouldn't stand here** !
>   You shouldn't **be** standing here, *(should you)*?

the difference may become more apparent

Comment: I think your first sentence has things completely reversed. OP's first version is "hypothetical" in that it can reasonably be said in a situation where the conversants are *not* in fact "standing here" (i.e. - walking past a spot where they *might* stand, but the speaker is counselling against that). In the second version it's almost an absolute certainty the conversants are currently standing here.

Comment: I **never said whether or if they were standing anywhere** in the first scenario. I think you've assumed that.

Comment: Well, if ***I*** haven't understood what you're saying, when I'm a native speaker, that doesn't bode well for OP (or any other nns users who might be looking at this answer now or in the future).